# Get MySQL data in a form when selected a with mysql data filled dropdown box

Tags: php, mysql, drop-down-menu

I'm trying to make a dropdown box which gets filled with data of a MySQL database. This is already working!

Now here's where I got stuck: when I select anything out of this Dropdown box I want the script to show me the other data which is in the same row in other columns.

Cam you help me with this?

Here's what I got until now:

```
<?php 
include('include.php');
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id ASC";
    $result = mysql_query($sql) OR die(mysql_error()); 
?> 
<select name="firma" style="width:200pt"> 
<?php 
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) { 
        echo '<option value="'. $row['id'] .'">'. $row['kunde'] .' ('. $row['kundennr'] .')</option>'."\n"; 
    }

?> 
</select>
```

I searched for it but I couldn't find anything!

It would be awesome, if anyone could help me with this!

Greets,
Alexander

Comment: What have you think about? Redirect to another page and show the result? Or do you want to stay there and show the result with jquery or something like this?

Comment: yes stay there using either jquery or javascript..
javascript would be better..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give your selectbox an Id

```
<select id="selectcompany" name="firma" style="width:200pt">
```

I don't know if this is possible with only javascript but here is an example with jQuery:

addresult.js :

```
$("select#selectcompany").ready(function(){
    $("select#selectcompany").on('change',function(){
         clearTimeout(delayTimer);
             delayTimer= setTimeout(function(){
                 $.post("getResult.php", {"selectedValue" : $(this).val()}, function(data){
                     if(data.length > 0) {
                         $('#result').empty();
                         $('#result').show();
                         $each(data,function(key,value){
                             $('#result').append('<input id="resultvalue" type="text" value="'+value+'" />');
                         }
                         $("#resultvalue").attr("readonly","true");                             

                     }      
                 }); 
        }, 500);
    });  
});
```

You will need an

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

or something like this, where your result should be shown.

In your PHP function you only need to echo the data which you would like to show.
jQuery will receive your information and save it in the variable data.

Then it depends on you, how you will display it.

Hope i could help you :)
I don't know if this works without some kind of errors, because untested.

Edit:

In your php function you can create an Array an return it in JSON:

```
echo json_encode($myArray);
```

in the  part you have to make this:

```
<head>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" src="addresult.js"></script>
</head>
```

and in the Body where you want the Result appear you should create

```
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks!
i want to display the data in inputfields set to readonly. :)

Comment: Sorry..
i don't get it work. :(
actually i don't really know how i use this with my problem... :/

Comment: Okay.. I got that so far...
now I get "null" shown.
How do i define which collum of the Database should be shown where?

Comment: The part with $.post will send an $_POST['selectedValue'] to your getResult.php.
In your first Post it would be the $row['id'].(your option value).
What you do here, depends on your need. :)
My Filenames i used are only for example, if you need you can rename then, but you have to edited them in code too.

Comment: so i just create an input field:
<input value="<?php $row['id'] ?>">for the fielt where i want to show the id for ex.?

Comment: getResult will receive the $_POST variable with this Variable you can what you want. Execute a second Query and get the information do you want and then give it back to the jQuery with echo json_encode($myArray); $myArray contains your information you like to show in the div.

Comment: but where dows this $_POST variable get the information?

I'M really sorry, but i'm not very good at this.

Comment: this part here : "selectedValue" : $(this).val()    will get the value of the selectbox when you select one entry of your entrys and will send it to getResult.php.

Comment: so if i say 
print_r($_POST);
it should print the selection or am I missunderstanding sth?

Comment: With print_r($POST); In your script getResult.php your will get the $row['id'] value return. This means, we send the <option> value.

Comment: If i write print_r($_POST); nothing is written..
But " echo json_encode($myArray);" just writes "null"...
what could be the problem?
Isn't it possible, to load all of the Data of the row which I choose by the Drop Down box and just write the data with e.g. "'. $row['name'] .' or something..?
Greets

Comment: what should be in the getResult.php?

Comment: getResult should receive your POST-Variable and execute a Query to get your information you need.Maybe you could join my chat, i will help you there further

Comment: i don't have enough reputations to join in a chat here.. :(
any where else?

Comment: have anything else where we can chat?
or email?